# C - fgets doesnt wait for input when initializing pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, io

I am making very basic programs to check how fputs and fgets work, and something strange is happening. The following code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    char* word;
    char* a;
    int k = 3;

    fgets(word, k, stdin);
    fputs(word, stdout);

    free(word);

    return 0;
}
```

by "fine" I mean that the program waits for an input and then prints that input (up to 2 digits - because the last one is '\0' I assume -) so that is ok. The char* a is unused, I know.

What seems strange to me is that when I initialize char* a = NULL, so the new code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

    char* word;
    char* a = NULL;
    int k = 3;

    fgets(word, k, stdin);
    fputs(word, stdout);

    free(word);

    return 0;
}
```

now the fgets does not wait for stdin input. I am not even using char* a at all so I don't see how can this initialization cause any problem. Can anyone explain this? Any other corrections/suggestions on the code submitted are welcome!

Comment: Both behaviors of the two codes are undefined behaviour. `char* word;` --> `char* word = malloc(3);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code invokes *Undefined Behavior* in both cases, since you are trying to store the input in a pointer that doesn't point to any memory block! That explains the inconsistency you observe.

---

Change this:

```
char* word;
```

to this:

```
char* word = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
```

---

Or, better, use an array: `char word[k];`, or use a constant (and probably a bigger line length — I'd suggest `4096`, partly for shock value, but mostly because it won't cause trouble and will head off trouble).

Comment: Or, better, use an array: `char word[k];`, or use a constant (and probably a bigger line length — I'd suggest 4096, partly for shock value, but mostly because it won't cause trouble and will head off trouble).

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question, but to be sure... I was thinking that fgets allocated the memory needed for the pointer 'word', from your answer now I think I was incorrect and memory must be allocated before using fgets, am I right? Furthermore, there will be no way of solving this using dynamic memory for 'word' as I was trying, because in order to do that I must know a priori what is the length of the input, which is not the case. Is this right?

Comment: `fgets()` doesn't allocate any space for you, so yes. Well if you statically allocate memory, you will still have to "guess" the size of your array, right? There are approaches to tackle this issue, but this is a new question. ;) So yes in both cases.